# How can i give my Users their own profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a car review website where Users are able to review cars, view news articles and write a personal blog about certain cars e.t.c. I have made a login system using devise, where users can log in and log out. However, I'm confused in how to get sessions to work. i.e. a user can write a review from their account and others would be able to see it, but would not be allowed to edit it or change it. Sorry for my bad wording. I would like my users to have their own personal account, like a facebook profile if you will. Are their any tutorials or gems that could help.

Comment: That's a redundant question check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458723/using-devise-to-create-private-profiles

Comment: What you're wanting to do is going to take a bit of work. I would suggest getting a book on this topic from amazon. You'll be better off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent resource by Michael Hartl,
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial

The first 7-8 chapters covers user sign in and session management.